# angular ng build --prod doesn't ignore unused/unimported components

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-aot

I have a couple of components which are part of a template which I dont use but don't what to physically delete.

I have commented out every import statement and reference to the component class but I'm still getting the error when running

ng build --prod

> Cannot determine the module for class OrganizationComponent

Is there a way to explicitly tell angular to ignore them? As far as I know the aot should ignore it on default...

Comment: I've added an answer which might help, but if you could post the code somewhere it would allow us a better chance of helping you. Can you cut it down to a minimal example and post it somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

The error posted implies that something is trying to instantiate that component but it is not referenced in any of the loaded modules.

This suggests that you have correctly removed it from the imports and the modules, but I would guess that perhaps you are still referencing the component's tag in a template of another component which is included?

Answer (score 0):

> Tree shaking is a step in a build process that removes unused code
>   from a code base.
>
> Tree shaking is a term commonly used in the JavaScript context for
>   dead-code elimination. It relies on the static structure of ES2015
>   module syntax, i.e. import and export.

For more Info: https://coryrylan.com/blog/tree-shakeable-providers-and-services-in-angular